# Rails 3.0 intermittent Connection timed out, execution expired errors

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, amazon-ec2

We're on four Amazon EC2 instances (one load balancer, one db, and two app) and are constantly getting random timeouts. We get at least one a day, sometimes more. Here are some examples:

```
Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2)
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:546:in `initialize'
```

and

```
Timeout::Error: execution expired
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activemodel-3.0.9/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:354:in `match'
```

I'm not sure how to debug these as they are not related to application code or server load. CPU usage usually hovers below 10% with the biggest spike going up to 60%. The spikes are most likely due to running backups and do not correspond with the times of the timeout errors.

How can these types of errors be tracked down?

Comment: I've tracked down the second issue. It turned out to be an application problem. There was some code that got stuck in a loop so it looked like the problem was elsewhere. The first one, I'm still not sure of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first timeout looks like a legit connection timeout sending mail via SMTP.  Are you hosting your own SMTP server or using a service?

Looks like sendgrid has been [experiencing delays/timeouts](http://twitter.com/#!/sendgrid_ops/status/108570305554948096) the last couple of days:

> We're currently seeing lots of volume in our queues and emails may be delayed for a short period. Stay tuned for updates. #status

**Fix for SMTP Service Timeout/Fails**

Setup a local mail relay that will hold mail and re-send if there are failures like this. We use a local Postfix relay in production for just this problem (so ActiveMailer uses sendmail to Postfix, which queues up mail and delivers via SMTP relay to Sendgrid).

Comment: I've seen dozens of these errors, not just in the last couple of days. I will file an issue with Sendgrid and see what they say.

Comment: If you're using raw Rails SMTP to Sendgrid, you may want to setup a local mail relay that will hold mail and re-send if there are failures like this.  We use a local Postfix relay in production for just this problem (so ActiveMailer uses sendmail to Postfix, which queues up mail and delivers via SMTP relay to Sendgrid).